# Make all images file point to CDN using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, cdn

In Ruby on Rails you can just adjust a single line of code to make all the assets use an external assets server. Inside `config/environments/production.rb` you just uncomment a line:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'XXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net'
```

So I would like to do the same on a react app. I have used [s3-plugin-webpack](https://github.com/MikaAK/s3-plugin-webpack) to upload all the assets but I have having problem changing the url to point to the new images that have just been uploaded.

I work on a isomorphic React app so it render both on server and client side. So I don't looking to make the application run from the CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring `{output: {publicPath: 'https://cdn.foo.com/me'}}` for your production builds. The URLs in the compilation should then point to the assets on the CDN.

Alternatively, you can configure [`cdnizer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cdnizer) with the plugin which should transform all the URLs in the HTML files in your output.